# Multi Level/ Hierarchy Time series

Tags: r, time-series

I have a dataframe (df), which has dates of last two years

**Data:**

```
Country State County  2015-01-01   2015-02-01 2015-03-01
IN       A     a       400          500       300    
IN       A     b       231          535       214
IN       B     a       532          212       242
........So on  .......................
```

**Objective:**

I want to build time series models for each combination, and get the forecast for say next 3 months

**Expected Result:**

```
Country State County  2015-01-01 2015-02-01 2015-03-01  .... 2017-01-01  
IN       A     a       400          500       300            421 
IN       A     b       231          535       214            231
IN       B     a       532          212       242            313
   ......... so on for all combination......
```

**Problem:**

How build models at each level/combination (at country level, at country and state level)?

I tired the following:

```
library(broom) 

time_series_models <- df %>% rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(forecasted_values = forecast(ets(ts(df[3:NCOL(df)], 
                                             start = c(2015, 5), frequency = 12), h= 4)))
```

**Problem:**

Error :  y should be a univariate time series

Comment: I don't know timeseries models, but using broom and dplyr, one can perform modelling by subgroups. see [the vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/broom/vignettes/broom_and_dplyr.html) for details. `tidy()` from broom supports time series data.

Comment: Will check this thanks